# EF Core Optional Foreign Keys On Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some models set up that look a bit like this (using this for simplification):

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Rating Rating { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public Guid RatingId { get; set; }
    public int StarRating { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have a dropdown for a rating on a blog record. I want to be able to add and delete different ratings and want any blogs with that rating to have a null value for those that have been removed. Right now it's not possible since I'm using Guids that are non-nullable. I'm thinking about changing the Id for just these optional relationships to a nullable type.

Convention-wise, what's the best nullable type to use? Should I replace all the Id's in my app, or just the ones I need to be nullable? I like uniformity, but that will be a lot of work to switch all the id types.

Comment: What's wrong with a nullable guid?

Comment: I tried and EF yelled at me. It said I have to switch to the preview version to use that.

Comment: Think I'm going to just switch to string Ids. EF creates guids from string Ids anyways, so the db will look exactly the same.

Comment: aren't those Guid columns the primary key in the respective tables? can they have null values?

Comment: Well the `Blog.Rating` is a fk to the `Rating` pk. The pk obviously can't be null.